# How to use where condition in if statement which is already written in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, laravel, codeigniter

I have got a situation where the `$user_id` parameter is optional and I used to do this in codeigniter in the way written below. But I am not able to figure it out, How can I write this query in laravel's eloquent and query builder as well. Any help is much appreciated.

```
function get_user($user_id) { 
    $this->db->select('u.id as user_id, u.name, u.email, u.mobile');
    if($user_id != '') {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }
    return $this->db->get('users as u')->result();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Eloquent:

```
$modalObject = new ModelName::select('id as user_id', 'name', 'email', 'mobile');

if ($user_id) {
    $modalObject = $modalObject->where('user_id', $user_id);
}

return $modalObject->get();
```

Using Query Builder:

```
$builder = DB::table('users')->select('id as user_id', 'name', 'email', 'mobile');

if ($user_id) {
    $builder = $builder->where('user_id', $user_id);
}

return $builder->get();
```

Replace the `ModelName` with one defined for the table `users`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing:

```
$builder = Model::query();
if($user_id != '') {
     $builder->where('user_id', $user_id);
}

return $builder->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries